# Using gifshot to create gifs from array of base64 strings doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the [gifshot](https://github.com/yahoo/gifshot) library to create gifs from a canvas. I'm capturing the canvas using `canvas.toDataURL()`, storing those results in an array, and then passing the array to the gifshot function. This works perfectly fine in Chrome and IE, but in FF the gif never gets created. I can see that Firefox creates the temporary images of each "frame" in the DOM, but for some reason the `onerror` part of the image load is hit instead of the actual `onload`. I'm not sure why.

I'm really not sure what to try either. It's such a straight-forward method: simply pass an array of images to the gifshot function.

```
function createGif(array) {
    gifshot.createGIF({
        images: array
    }, function (obj) {
        if (!obj.error) {
            var image = obj.image,
                animatedImage = document.createElement('img');
            animatedImage.src = image;
            document.body.appendChild(animatedImage);
        }
    });
}
```

Where `array` is the base64 strings. Passing something like imgur links instead (like in their example) works just fine. It's just the array of base64 strings that FF doesn't like. I've checked, in FF, and the array that's being passed is just fine.

Here's a jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dxdn6s3h/2/. Works in IE/Chrome, doesn't in FF.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  I'm having the same issue.  Inspecting the dom, I see those temporary images as well, with `crossorigin="Anonymous"` on each.

Comment: @calipoop sorry, I never did figure that out. I ended up using gif.js instead. That being said, I just tried that jsfiddle link in my question and it seems to work in FF now.

Answer (score 3):

i am working with gifshot also and i figured out that i need to separately init Image object and add it to the array. Below code is more clear:

```
var images = [];
var oneImage = new Image();
oneImage.src = base64ImageString;
images.push(oneImage);
```

And then use your code to export the gif image.
Hope this post can help you :)